# MySql and NodeJS: Best Way to Insert Into two tables?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, backend

Building simple ToDo app in React frontend/Express+NodeJS backend with MySQL. I have three tables: Tasks, Groups, and Users. Users are meant to join a group, with access to Tasks controlled by Group membership. The Users table is the linking table with two columns, UserId and GroupId.

I'm trying to figure out the best SQL query to allow a user to create a group and be added to it at the same time, which requires creating rows in both Groups and Users table. Here is my route:

```
module.exports = app => {
    const group = require("../controllers/group.controller.js");
    const checkJwt = require("../middleware/check-jwt");

    var router = require("express").Router();

    // Create a new Group
    router.post("/", checkJwt, group.create);

    app.use('/api/profile', router);
};
```

Group.controller:

```
const Family = require("../models/family.model.js");
var { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");

// Create and Save a new Group
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Validate request
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Content can not be empty!"
        });
    }

    // Create a Group
    const Group = new group({
        groupId: req.body.groupId,
        groupName: req.body.groupName,
        userId: req.body.userId,
    });

    // Save Group in the database
    Group.create(Group, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the group."
            });
        else res.send(data);
    });
};
```

Group.model is below. This is what I CURRENTLY have which can successfull add a row to the groups table:

```
const sql = require("./db.js");

// constructor
const Group = function(group) {
    this.groupId = group.groupId;
    this.groupName = group.groupName; 
};

Group.create = (newGroup, result) => {
    sql.query("INSERT INTO groups SET ?", newGroup, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
            return;
        }

        console.log("created group: ", { groupId: res.insertId, ...newGroup });
        result(null, { groupId: res.insertId, ...newGroup });
    });
};
```

...but I also want to turn around and immediately create a row in the Users table, consisting of userId and the new groupId. So I add userId to my constructor, which is coming in from my frontend request:

```
const Group = function(group) {
        this.groupId = group.groupId;
        this.groupName = group.groupName;
        this.userId = group.userId;
    };
```

...and my problem now is that I don't know how to add the second row, as you can only do a single INSERT INTO per query. Also, how to grab the newly created groupId from the previous query? If anyone has thoughts,  suggestions, or examples to share, please let me know.

Comment: So execute 2 selerate queries, preferably inside a transaction

Comment: https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/06/how-to-retrieve-the-last-inserted-id-with-node-js-mysql/